# Why is my HTTP/2 stream slower than HTTP/1.1 and HTTPS

Tags: performance, nginx, http2

For my study I am analysing the performance of HTTP/2 in contrast to HTTP/1.1 and HTTPS.

For my test I load a set of 128 images to see if HTTP/2 benefits with its multiplexed stream. The images have in each test run a size of 2KB, 20KB and 50KB, respectively.

[I got the following results for Page Load Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foHK2.jpg)

Initially, i would have assumed HTTP/2 would be faster than HTTP/1.1 or maximal as fast as HTTP/1.1. But why is HTTP/2 by more than 20% slower in the test runs with 20KB and 50KB. Has anyone a clue what the reason could be?

I am using on the server-side nginx 1.10.0.
On the client-side chrome. Latency: 50ms. Packet Loss is low.

Comment: With only the outcome and no further details about the case you're measuring, there is not much people can give advice on. Perhaps you can elaborate on what is loading exactly, such as amount of assets, detailed description of the http requests and to what types of assets. Or, even better, a reproduceable sample of your test code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I will help someone.
So, I think the reason is in your browser. Modern browsers know that HTTP 1.1 is slow, hence they can open up to 6 connections (by default) at once.

When you are sending big images, there is a huge chance to lose at least one TCP  segment. Because of this loss, http2 *waits* until the segment will be received.
Http1.1 too. But there are 6 connections in that case, only 1 stopped.

How to fix? It is one of the main problems solved in HTTP3.

Read more: https://www.oreilly.com/content/will-http2-make-my-site-faster/

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a test with Jetty (disclaimer, I am the HTTP/2 Jetty maintainer).

Jetty 9.4.2, JDK 8u121, simulated network roundtrip 50 ms (via `tc`).

20 images, 2k each:

```
HTTP/1.1:    ~275 ms
HTTP/2:      ~170 ms
HTTP/2 Push: ~155 ms
```

20 images, 20k each:

```
HTTP/1.1:    ~380 ms
HTTP/2:      ~200 ms
HTTP/2 Push: ~155 ms
```

20 images, 50k each:

```
HTTP/1.1:    ~380 ms
HTTP/2:      ~220 ms
HTTP/2 Push: ~155 ms
```

Beside this quick test, the experience we have is that HTTP/2 multiplexing is indeed effective in reducing the latency for the end user.
HTTP/2 with HTTP/2 Push is even better.
This is also confirmed by the large number of HTTP/2 demos you can find online.

The code for the quick test above can be found [here](https://github.com/jetty-project/http2-demo).

I suspect it may be some nginx issue, perhaps related to flow control (since you have issues only at larger image sizes).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was suspecting the same thing, that flow control is the issue. Any ideas how i could solve this problem with nginx?

Comment: Report the issue to the nginx project.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinon,

HTTP/2, determined by its machanisms, reveals speed advantages over HTTP/1.1 when these conditions (but not limited) are met:

1. many parallel requests
2. small request/response payloads
3. high RTT value

If most of above conditions are unmet (e.g. downloading single large file), then HTTP/2 may perform worse than HTTP/1.1.